# What is the meaning of TIME_KILL_SYNCHRONOUS?

Tags: c#, winmm

I wrote a C# wrapper for multimedia timer:
The `Start` method calls `timeSetEvent` with the user-specified callback and the `Stop` method simply calls `timeKillEvent`.

I have a unit test which is supposed to check that `Stop` works:

```
using (var timer = new HighResolutionTimer(20))
{
    int counter = 0;
    timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    timer.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(40);
    timer.Stop();
    //Thread.Sleep(10);
    int old = counter;
    Assert.AreNotEqual(0, old);
    Thread.Sleep(40);
    Assert.AreEqual(old, counter);
}
```

My problem is that sometimes this test fails because the event occurs one more time after I call `Stop`. I tried adding the `TIME_KILL_SYNCHRONOUS` flag at creation but it doesn't seem to work.
I can't understand from the documentation what exactly it is supposed to do. According to MSDN:

> Creating an event with the TIME_KILL_SYNCHRONOUS and the
>   TIME_CALLBACK_FUNCTION flag prevents the event from occurring after
>   the timeKillEvent function is called.

Does this mean that any pending events won't get executed? Or rather maybe the `timeKillEvent` method will not return after all the pending events are executed?

I searched online but couldn't find an answer.

In any case, this doesn't help my tests. The only way I can get my tests to always pass is to add a short `Sleep` after I call `Stop`.

Comment: I assume it means that the cancellation function doesn't return until the timer is cancelled. i.e. once control is back with you, the timer is cancelled and therefore the callback function will not be called.

Comment: By the way, I hope you noted that timeSetEvent is now obsolete

Comment: @ta.speot.is This doesn't coincide with the fact that my test still didn't pass after I set this flag.

Comment: @o_weisman Yes, I did. I read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/09/08/462477.aspx and http://omeg.pl/blog/2011/11/on-winapi-timers-and-their-resolution/ and decided that the multimedia timer is better for my needs.

Comment: Why don't you make the timer one shot and that way it'll never fire more than once? By the way, you can't be sure when the Stop command reaches the timer as it is on another thread. If it runs periodically, there's a good chance that it'll fire again even after you called Stop.